# apache virtual host accesed as other domain - how to stop it?

Tags: apache, misuse

I have few virtual hosts on my server (say `\*.mydomain.com`), but I got lots of "spam/hack requests" for some totally other domain, like `xchecker.net`

```
 91.122.59.90 - - [2019-09-06 18:09:35] "POST http://fdc.xchecker.net/proxy2017/http/engine16.php HTTP/1.0" 403 302 #  "http://fdc.xchecker.net/proxy2017/http/engine16.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0"
```

while my domain is nothing like *.*.net - those request fails because they ask for non-existent files,

```
[Fri Sep 06 18:14:50.416879 2019] [authz_core:error] [pid 226975] [client 5.136.243.174:56314] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/htdocs, referer: RefererString
```

but I would like to reject them even earlier, as they ask for domain I do not even have.

I tried something like

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} .*http.* [NC]
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !.*mydomain.com.* [NC]
    RewriteRule ^.* - [G,L]
```

but it did not work at all

How should I reject such requests just based on bad domain access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was, that I had each **virtual host** in **different file** and **common file** alloved to set things like

```
LogFormat "%>s # %h %l %u %{[%F %T]}t \"%r\" %>s %b #  \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" common
```

but did not enabled set (additional) **Rewrite Engine** configuration.

So I included to each virtual host file those lines:

```
RewriteEngine on
Include /etc/apache2/vhosts.d/x-my-rules
```

(maybe followed by more rules like this (for site I want make mostly private))

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*(google).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*(bot|spider|Ankit|Bing).* [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* - [G,L]
```

and created common include file `x-my-rules`

```
 #  LogLevel warn rewrite:trace6
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} .*http(s)?:.* [NC]
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !.*mydomain.com.* [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [G,L]
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !(GET\ |POST\ |HEAD\ ).* [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [G,L]
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} .*\./.* [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [G,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*(xchecker.net|blabol).* [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (Ankit|Bing) [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [G,L]
```

(Which is not perfect, but works for me to fight following:

- `http://fdc.xchecker.net/proxy201..` totally different site
- `CONNECT some/service` which I do not even host
- `GET ../../mnt/Datafile` try to get files out of structure
- traffick from `xchecker.net` to nonexistent files
- I do not like `Bing` and there was many attacks by `Ankit` bot

and I will later go thru logs again and add more rules, for other tries to misuse of my site)